# Local variable - how to access in other if-sling(python)

Tags: python, variables

Sorry for not printing in english but that would´t helped.

I have three menu options(MenyVal). I don´t want it to be possible to choose option 2 and 3 before option 1. Therefore I´ve tried with "block" which is supposed to make it impossible to choose 2 or 3 before 1.

The problem is that block as I understand it is local and become 0 again after option 1 which keeps you from making option 2 or 3 after option 1.

How do I do to keep the value 1 for block(after option one) when the user is moving on to option 2 and 3?
I can´t have global variables.

```
while Korning == "1":

    Menyrader()
    MenyVal= input("Ange ditt menyval med en siffra:")
    block = 0
    if MenyVal== "1": 
        try:               
          AntalSpelare= input("Ange hur många spelare som ska delta:")
          VarvTak= int(AntalSpelare) * 16  
          AntalVarv = 0
          protokoll, spelarnamn = SkapaSpelare(momentlist, AntalSpelare)
          block = 1

        except:
            print("Felaktig inmatning, försök igen.")                   

    elif MenyVal== "2":
        #print(block)
        if block != 0:
            GePoang(protokoll, momentlist)

            for namn in protokoll:
                namn.SummeraForstaSex()
                namn.SummeraAlla()

            AntalVarv += 1
            Utskrift(protokoll, momentlist, spelarnamn)
            TestaStopp(VarvTak, AntalVarv)
        else:
            print("Du måste först lägga till spelare")

    elif MenyVal== "3":
        if block != 0:  
            Stryka(protokoll)

            for namn in protokoll:
                namn.SummeraForstaSex()
                namn.SummeraAlla()

            AntalVarv += 1
            Utskrift(protokoll, momentlist, spelarnamn)
            TestaStopp(VarvTak, AntalVarv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`block` is reiniitialized to `0` in each iteration of the `while` loop. To avoid this, just define it **before** the loop:

```
block = 0
while Korning == "1":

    Menyrader()
    MenyVal= input("Ange ditt menyval med en siffra:")
    if MenyVal== "1": 
        try:               
          AntalSpelare= input("Ange hur många spelare som ska delta:")
          VarvTak= int(AntalSpelare) * 16  
          AntalVarv = 0
          protokoll, spelarnamn = SkapaSpelare(momentlist, AntalSpelare)
          block = 1

        except:
            print("Felaktig inmatning, försök igen.")

     -- Rest of the code here...
```